# PhpMyAdmin: Насколько критически данные замечания?

Tags: phpmyadmin, база-данных, сервер, localhost, mysql

Просто у меня возникли проблемы с с некоторыми фреймворками, а именно установки их, иногда возникают ошибки, поэтому и спрашиваю:

[image]

ну например на joomla не хочет создаваться категория, хотя на хостинге все норм, phpinfo(); - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn3KS.png

нда... Хотелось как лучше, а получилось как всегда.

Comment: Вы сами устанавливали php и веб-сервер? Вероятно у вас устаревшая версия php и не подключено множество расширений, так необходимых "некоторым фреймворкам".

А лучше `phpinfo()` в студию - там больше информации о том какая версия и что установлено. И по конкретней расскажите о каких фреймворках идёт речь.

Comment: Да, шрифт мелковат :-)))

Answer (score 1):

Первые 2 ошибки не критичны и касаются только phpMyAdmin (его версией и настройками). Т.е. на Joomla они никак, в общем-то, влиять не могут.

Третья — не критична. Влияет на все на сервере, что пытается работать с модулем mbstring PHP. Выразилось бы в ругани на отсутствие модуля mbstring или отсутствии функций с именами `mb_...` — Вы бы поняли, что это оно.

Последняя — тоже не критична; все должно быть совместимо. Но лучше, если есть возможность, исправить — может, при особом невезении, если вдруг где-то что-то поменяли в протоколе, вызывать странное поведение связанное с БД. Хотя это и маловероятно.

Исправлять, разумеется, лучше все. Но если есть более важные вопросы — ничего из приведенного не «горит».